# Unable to align buttons which have + & - sign

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons which have + and - . I am unable to get both the buttons of the same width. And if I use css width property, the signs don't look  aligned centrally.

```
<span class="button-inner">
    <input type="submit" value="-" rel="rc1">
</span>
<br>
<span class="button-inner">
    <input type="submit" value="+" rel="rc2">
</span>
```

My Css:

```
input[rel^="rc"] {
    width: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The - and + signs are not centralized or don't have equal padding on both sides
[image: The - and + signs are not centralized or don't have equal padding on both sides]

Comment: Please elaborate how they look 'off', I see this code working as intended in a fiddle.

Comment: Updated with image

Comment: Basically the + & - sign dont take up the same column width

Comment: Im unable to reproduce, is there a parent element with css? Mine are perfectly centered with your code

Comment: You might have some other CSS overwriting your buttons, it is showing correctly for me in CodePen

Comment: Perhaps theres a browser property, try just throwing in `padding: 0` on that css class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are going in the right direction by using the width property but as you said, the + and - characters are not aligning in the center. You can add the property

```
text-align:center;
```

and that almost fixes it... It does still look like the + and - are to the right. This is because the width is not wide enough. In this [jsfiddle,](https://jsfiddle.net/sq8aba3v/) a width of 8% seems to do the trick.

probable fix:

```
input[rel^="rc"] {
width: 8%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:center;
```

}

see it here https://jsfiddle.net/sq8aba3v/

Comment: With 5% it looks fine on chrome but no on Firefox. I am not looking for a wide button. I am looking for as small as a button as possible. I know increasing width will make it work

Comment: While this should have a `min-width` with a solid px value, changing the relative width does not solve this problem